# sonar/jacoco plugin failed due to API incompatibility

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

we have use sonar/jacoco for our code coverage, and one it stopped working, and the error message is:

> Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project prism-parent-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar failed: Unable to load the mojo 'sonar' in the plugin 'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/SonarQubeMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

After some painful comparison of before and after logs, I found out the sonar-maven-plugin change from version 3.0.2 to 3.2, even though there is no change to the pom file.

I also run 'mvn dependency:tree' and don't see any dependency of sonar.

Last i updated the pom to specify the sonar-maven-plugin version to enforce it to use the version that used to work, but it still doesn't help, here is my parent pom

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>coverage-per-test</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <properties>
                <property>
                  <name>listener</name>
                  <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                </property>
              </properties>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <properties>
                <property>
                  <name>listener</name>
                  <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                </property>
              </properties>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
          <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
          <version>2.7</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    </profiles>
```

is there anything wrong in my pom?

Answer (score 3):

In Java cause of

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

is that version of used JVM is lower than version for which class files were compiled. "52.0" refers to Java 8 and this version is indeed [required starting from SonarQube version 5.6](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-ecosystem-upgrades-to-java-8/). All in all, I'm pretty sure that SonarQube server has been upgraded, while you use Java lower than 8.